# Overriding initialize method into model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, object-initializers

I'm trying to override the initialize method. See below

```
class Restriction < ActiveRecord::Base
  RESTRICTION_TYPES = {
    less_than: "IND<X", 
    greater_than: "X<IND", 
    between: "X<IND<Y"
  }

  def initialize restriction_type_name
    super
    formula = RESTRICTION_TYPES[restriction_type_name]
  end

  private
  def formula=f
    self[:formula] = f
  end

end
```

When I run `r = Restriction.new(:between)` I get the exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for :between:Symbol
```

What am I doing wrong?

BTW I'm doing this due to `formula` attribute can't be acceded from outside.

Comment: Really not a good idea. ActiveRecord does a lot of magic behind the scenes around the initialize method.

Comment: I read about that. So what is the best solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override `initialize`, and what you have wouldnt work anyway (it would try to set a local variable called `formula` in the initialize method). You can, however, move the conditions into your `formula=` setter, so it reads like:

```
def formula=(restriction_type_name)
  self[:formula] = RESTRICTION_TYPES[restriction_type_name]
end
```